# Validate forms by function

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, alert

I have strange problem. I'm trying validate my form by function in JavaScript in this way:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return validate();" name="valideButton" value="Something" />
```

And the validate function:

```
function validate() {

    alert("Some alert!");

    var someValidateInputName = document.forms["formName"]["someValidateInputName"].value;

    alert(someValidateInputName);

    if (someValidateInputName == "0") {
        alert("Wrong value: " + document.forms["formName"]["someValidateInputName"].value);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

When I use `alert(document.forms["formName"]["someValidateInputName"].value)` inside my form there's everything allright, but when I'm calling function `validate();` I have an alert with `Some alert`, but I don't have alert with `someValidateInputName`. It seems like a function `return true` when I try to check `someValidateInputName` and I don't know why...

The script with function is in the same file above the html code.
I validate form on the other my pages in the same way and there was no problem.

Comment: alert("Some alert!); should be alert("Some alert!");

Comment: Did you try to do validation `onsubmit` for form itself?

Comment: Yes I try, but onsubmit doesn't work at all, even on my other pages. So I decide to use onClick and calling the function. Like I wrote, this works on my other sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solve the problem.
It was a stupid mistake... and I think that nobody could not help me without more information.
I skip this, because I forget that this can be so important.

My `form` was closed in `foreach` loop and many input has `name="someValidateInputName"`, so my outside function doesn't know which input I want to validate. I don't look at the problem in this way, because for me it was strange that function always return true when only I try read the input value.

If somebody forget about this like me, here is the solve:
We need to adding an indexes to name of form and name of input like this:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return validate();" name="valideButton <?php echo $j; ?>" value="Something" />
```

In the same way we have to add index to name of form.
And I send my Index to read the right value via $_POST. I increment `$j` too.

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $j++; ?>" name="Index" />
```

At the end my `validation()` look like this:

```
function validate(index) {

    alert("Some alert!");

    var someValidateInputName = document.forms["formName"+index]["someValidateInputName"+index].value;

    alert(someValidateInputName);

    if (someValidateInputName == "0") {
        alert("Wrong value: " + document.forms["formName"+index]["someValidateInputName"+index].value);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

If you could place the `form` out of the `foreach` you don't be need to an index to form.

Thanks for the trying help!
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

`alert("Some alert!);` should be `alert("Some alert!");` the way it is now it tries to alert everything untill the next " meaning it tries to alert half your function.

Comment: ok, there is a mistake only in my post. In code I have ` alert("Some alert!");`. Sorry about that. Still is the problem.

Comment: @user3166192 I'm not that experienced in JavaScript but what if you try: `document.forms["formName"]["someValidateInputName"].innerHTML;` instead of `document.forms["formName"]["someValidateInputName"].value;`?

Comment: No, there is the same problem. When I try use JS function it automatically returns true.

Comment: @user3166192 Hmm, that's strange. Can you try to use this in de 2nd alert: `alert(document.forms["formName"]["someValidateInputName"].value);` see if something like this works. Remember i'm not good with javascript so im just trying whatever i think.

Comment: @user3166192 Also, maybe you can build an `if` statement in your function. `If (POST data is set) {alert("Post data is set");} else {alert("isn't set");}` This way you know if it retrieves the data correctly or not

Comment: I have to change the DB model on my website, so I will be continue fight with problem after that.
But thanks a lot for interesting in my problem.